# Get authenticated data via other methods

Tags: php, jquery

So I'm running into an issue and I can't seem to figure it out, so I'm reaching out to see if anyone can help me.

I have a method called `show_instagram_table()` which has the following:

```
private function show_instagram_table(): string
    {
        $table = '';
        if ($authenticated_users = get_option('instagram_authenticated_users')) {
            foreach ($authenticated_users as $authenticated_user) {
                $table .= '<table class="widefat"><tbody>';
                // ----------- Remove other items non-needed ---------------
                if (Instagram::get_items()) {
                    $table .= $this->show_authenticated_buttons($authenticated_user);
                }
                $table .= '</tbody></table>';
            }
        }

        return $table;
}
```

Which calls on `show_authenticated_buttons()`:

```
private function show_authenticated_buttons($user): string
{
    $buttons = '<tr>';
    $buttons .= $this->show_deauthorize_instagram_button($user);
    $buttons .= '</tr>';

    return $buttons;
}
```

This calls on `show_deauthorize_instagram_button()`:

```
private function show_deauthorize_instagram_button($user): string
{
    return '<td><button class="button button-primary instagram-deauthorize" style="margin-right: 5px">Deauthorize</button>';
}
```

---

Using AJAX, when the button is clicked, is will target that method and send the response back to PHP:

So..

```
jQuery('.instagram-deauthorize').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        'action': 'deauthorize_instagram_via_button',
    };
    jQuery.post(instagram_object.ajax_url, data, function() {
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Will trigger this method (I've tested it, it deletes the option):

```
public function deauthorize_instagram_via_button($user)
{
    if (!get_option('instagram_authenticated_users')) {
        return;
    }
    $users = get_option('instagram_authenticated_users');
    if (count($users) === 1) {
        delete_option('instagram_authenticated_users');
        $this->instagram->delete_cache();
    }

    exit;
}
```

**Here is where I am stuck**:

I am wanting to send `authenticated_user` data inside the foreach from `show_instagram_table` all the way to my `deauthorize_instagram_via_button()` method, but it's impossible for me to target it.

Does anyone know what I can change/improve? I've already tried passing it down using `$user` params and no luck.

(Sorry for the lack of pictures, I am not allowed to post them).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more attribute for each row.
You can use something like `data-id` or else.

For example :

```
private function show_authenticated_buttons($user): string
{
    $buttons = '<tr data-id="'.$user->id.'">';
    $buttons .= $this->show_deauthorize_instagram_button($user);
    $buttons .= '</tr>';

    return $buttons;
}
```

Then, you can get each user id (by using `$(this).attr("data-id")`).

```
jQuery('.instagram-deauthorize').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        'action': 'deauthorize_instagram_via_button',
        'user_id': $(this).attr("data-id")
    };
    jQuery.post(instagram_object.ajax_url, data, function() {
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Finally your `deauthorize_instagram_via_button` will get the user_id.

Comment: Thanks @Zaid, I'm testing this now - On the last portion, do how I access the `user_id` inside the php method `deauthorize_instagram_via_button`? I know the `$user` param doesn't work, is there another way?

Comment: I would need to use `user_id` inside a PHP piece of code inside `deauthorize_instagram_via_button`.

Comment: what is this value `instagram_object.ajax_url`? do use any framework of php? if not, you can try to debug `$_POST['user_id']` on your `deauthorize_instagram_via_button`.

Comment: I might not have made the AJAX request correct, I tried my best to basically click my button and a PHP method gets triggered, when I debug `$_POST['user_id']` all that I'm getting back is the action. `instagram_object.ajax_url` has no specific meaning.

Comment: `var data = {
    'action': 'deauthorize_instagram_via_button',
    'user_id': $(this).attr("data-id")
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: instagram_object.ajax_url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        // to do
    }
});`

How about that? Just copy paste and see the differences on your editor

Comment: I just tried it, seems to receive just the action again via $_POST and it's not passing down the user_id. I'm looking into it some more now.

Comment: ok, i am happy to help if you need, please consider give an upvote if you find this useful for you

Comment: I got it! :D - Thank you! My `$` was undefined in jQuery, needed to use jQuery.ajax.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)